# Can't post with postman, why?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postman

**employee.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Employee = mongoose.model('Employee', {
  name: { type: String },
  position: { type: String },
  office: { type: String },
  salary: { type: Number }
});

module.exports = { Employee };
```

**employeeController.js**

```
const express = require('express');

var router = express.Router();

var { Employee } = require('../models/employee');

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
Employee.find((err, docs) =>{
    if (!err) {res.send(docs);}
    else {console.log('Error in Retriving Employees: '+ JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2));}
   });
});

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
var emp = new Employee({
    name: req.body.name,
    position: req.body.position,
    office: req.body.office,
    salary: req.body.salary,
});
    emp.save((err, doc) => {
    if(!err) {res.send(doc); }
    else {console.log('Error in employee save:' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 
   2));}
 });
});

 module.exports = router;
```

**In postman I add:**

```
  {
"name":"Anida Mujezin",
"position":"Full stack developer",
"office":"Sarajevo",
"salary":3000
  }
```

**Error:**
Error in employee save:{
"driver": true,
"name": "MongoError",
"index": 0,
"code": 13297
}

and Could not get response in Postman

Comment: just read the error with `console.log(err)` or run `res.send(err)` in order to understand what is going on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the name of your database. That error code seems to indicate that a database with that name already has been created, and the name needs to be unique.

However, as the error message suggests, there is also a possibility that you have already created an employee with the name "Anida Mujezin", which I assume is used as the identifier in your database.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you created a database with the same name for eg **employee** previously, and now trying to use database called **Employee**, and you are using a **case-insensitive file system** (Windows?).

*Here employee and Employee would collide on the filesystem, and MongoDB is refusing to allow both to exist.*

Follow this for the Mongo error codes [mongo error codes](https://gist.github.com/rluvaton/a97a8da46ab6541a3e5702e83b9d357b)